# How to create a jsonpath to instagram business account in a batch request with the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, request, instagram, jsonp, batch-processing

My goal is to create a batch request with dependent calls as documented here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#operations

You can reference the results of a previous operation using JSONPath in form post parameters in addition to query string parameters.
I can't get the right JSONPath to make it work when there are multiple elements in the data array that have an instagram_business_account.id (iba_id)

The two calls that I want to make are 
/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account
/17841400714813297?fields=business_discovery.username(thomasguntenaar){media_count}
my batch looks like

```
[
{"method":"GET","name":"get-ig", "relative_url":"me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account"},
{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"{result=get-ig:$.data..instagram_business_account.id}?fields=business_discovery.username(thomasguntenaar){media_count}}"}
]
```

in the second query you are supposed to put the JSONPath to the instagram business account id 
after `result=`
I get this error back

```
 {
    "code": 404,
    "body": "{
   \"error\": {
      \"message\": \"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 17841400714813297,17841403388404550,17841401383243593\",
      \"type\": \"OAuthException\",
      \"code\": 803,
      \"fbtrace_id\": \"FV8qA+oA7fp\"
   }
}"
  }
```

Facebooks json response after the first call is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "466912700123917"
    },
    {
      "id": "502655553273897"
    },
    {
      "instagram_business_account": {
        "id": "17841400714813297"
      },
      "id": "503124266815195"
    },
    {
      "instagram_business_account": {
        "id": "17841403388404550"
      },
      "id": "510613645695833"
    },
    {
      "instagram_business_account": {
        "id": "17841401383243593"
      },
      "id": "2061834074114937"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "NDY2OTEyNzAwMTIzOTE3",
      "after": "MjA2MTgzNDA3NDExNDkzNwZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

When you query the second request like this
`?ids=17841400714813297,17841403388404550,17841401383243593&fields=business_discovery.username(thomasguntenaar){username,media_count}`
the response looks like this

```
{
  "17841400714813297": {
    "business_discovery": {
      "username": "thomasguntenaar",
      "media_count": 76,
      "id": "17841400714813297"
    },
    "id": "17841400714813297"
  },
  "17841403388404550": {
    "business_discovery": {
      "username": "thomasguntenaar",
      "media_count": 76,
      "id": "17841400714813297"
    },
    "id": "17841403388404550"
  },
  "17841401383243593": {
    "business_discovery": {
      "username": "thomasguntenaar",
      "media_count": 76,
      "id": "17841400714813297"
    },
    "id": "17841401383243593"
  }
}
```

Comment: Guess it could be due to the fact that you are getting multiple, comma separated IDs here, and not a single one on its own. Can you try the “alternate” syntax for your second request, instead of `/id?fields=...` use the `ids=` syntax, `?ids=multiple,ids,here&fields=…` - does that change things?

Comment: I kind of works?It seems that for every id you place after `ids=` you get a response. I did this `?ids=17841400714813297,17841403388404550,17841401383243593&fields=business_discovery.username(thomasguntenaar){username,media_count}`.

Comment: Yes, that is intended. `?ids=a,b,c` is basically the same as if you made three separated requests for ids `a`, `b` and `c`, and then combined the resulting data set afterwards.

Comment: Ah I see thank you for your help. Now when you discover a bit more information the response gets big a lot faster. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you want data for one specific IG account only, then you would have to figure out a way to have your first request only return that specific ID to begin with. If you request data for multiple ids, _and_ add more additional fields(?) - well yeah, then the resulting data set will grow larger. But if you wanted to limit that somehow, you’d need to first of all specify, what/how exactly.

Comment: I see two possible solutions, either I somehow specify to the Graph API that I only need 1 id, which I did look into but can't find the right parameters ,or I find/use a better JSONPath so that it will not present an array of id's. You can't use a filter tho, because of privacy reasons, and grabbing an index out of the array of id's returns error's as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 17841400714813297,17841403388404550,17841401383243593

Apparently the API thinks this was supposed to be *one* id, and doesn’t realize it is supposed to be three separate ones.

The API has a syntax to request data for more than one object in one request - instead of `/{id}?fields=foo`, you can make a request of the form `?ids={1,2,3}&fields=foo`, to request this data for the objects with ids 1, 2 and 3 in one go. The resulting data structure will contain a sub-structure for each of those ids.

The same structure should work in batch requests as well, when parts (here, the IG account ids returned by the previous query) are dynamically inserted.